# React Native - Android Native Component for Shadow

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building a React Native project that it's design relies largely on shadows.

Unfortunately there is no native support for shadows for android, and setting the `elevation` property does not meet my needs.

I'm looking desperately for a solution:

I've tried [`react-native-shadow`](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) - but it badly effects performance.

What I found is [this](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout) native android library for shadows that looks awesome, but I don't have the knowledge on putting it together with a [React Native UI Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android) I can use in my project.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323544/how-do-i-render-a-shadow ?

Comment: @Nima Its iOS - I'm looking for an android solution...

Comment: Would you want to apply the shadow using this library to any element, or any particular type?

Comment: @Lukasz Basically to any element, as children of the component...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ended up using this great Shadow Component:

https://github.com/ajinasokan/react-native-shadowview

It is a React Native UI component, that wraps an Android Native Component.

Exactly what I was looking for...
wasn't aware of it when asking question :)